# Transforming CAD File To shapefile (with Projection) Using FME Batch File

Tags: shapefile, convert, fme-form, cad, fme-transformer

I want to convert files from within my application. I've tried a lot, but I can't find a solution. 
I have a DXF file with which I know the projection system (EPSG:4326). And I want to transform it to a shapefile with projection.

Here are a few of my experiments;

```
fme gentrans ACAD "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1360\File.dxf" ESRISHAPE "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1360\SHP\" --_SOURCE_CSYS "EPSG:4326" --_DEST_CSYS "EPSG:3857"
or
fme gentrans ACAD "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1360\File.dxf" ESRISHAPE "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1360\SHP\" --_SOURCE_CSYS EPSG:4326 --_DEST_CSYS EPSG:3857
or
fme gentrans ACAD "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1360\File.dxf" ESRISHAPE "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1360\SHP\" --ACAD_COORDINATE_SYSTEM "EPSG:4326" --_DEST_CSYS "EPSG:3857"
or
fme gentrans ACAD "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1360\File.dxf" ESRISHAPE "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1360\SHP\" --ACAD_COORDINATE_SYSTEM EPSG:4326 --ESRISHAPE_COORDINATE_SYSTEM EPSG:3857
or
fme gentrans ACAD "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1360\File.dxf" COORDSYS, "EPSG:4326" ESRISHAPE "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1360\SHP\" COORDSYS, "EPSG:3857"
or
fme gentrans ACAD "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1360\File.dxf" COORDSYS, EPSG:4326 ESRISHAPE "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1360\SHP\" COORDSYS, EPSG:3857
or
fme gentrans ACAD "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1360\File.dxf" --COORDSYS "EPSG:4326" ESRISHAPE "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1360\SHP\" COORDSYS "EPSG:3857"
or
fme gentrans ACAD "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1360\File.dxf" --COORDSYS EPSG:4326 ESRISHAPE "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1360\SHP\" --COORDSYS EPSG:3857
```

This code will use in C# project.

When I use FME Desktop Translator then it output files has *.prj. (Total 4 files)

When i use FME Console App then it output files hasn't *.prj (Total 3 files - *.dbf, *.shp, *.shx)

How can i set projection system on converting process?

Answer (score 1):

You are aiming to convert between a DXF in WGS84 lat/lon to a shapefile in spherical mercator E/N.  When building the gentrans command, try using the coordinate system **name** rather than the EPSG code.  This should work:

```
fme gentrans ACAD "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1360\File.dxf" COORDSYS,LL84 ESRISHAPE "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1360\SHP\" COORDSYS,SPHERICAL_MERCATOR
```

Notes: No spaces in the COORDSYS argument.  Tested in FME v2017.0.1.1 win32.

There is further guidance on the gentrans function on the FME Knowledge Centre [here](https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/1398/using-fmes-gentrans-mode-1.html).

Comment: Hi JimT,
I tried ways of this site. I solved problem but cant close ticket.

Solution:
Create batch file using FME for same spatial files. I modified TCL files and send FME as argument. 

Thank you for your interest